# Archivo JSON a CSV en Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

me gustaría saber si alguien tiene una idea de como convertir un JSON en CSV en node.js

Por ejemplo este JSON:

```
var myObj = {
"Processes": [{
    "id": "p1",
    "burstTime": "3",
    "arribo": "0"
}, {
    "id": "p2",
    "burstTime": "4",
    "arribo": "1"
}, {
    "id": "p3",
    "burstTime": "5",
    "arribo": "2"
    }]
}
```

He leído que node.js tiene varias librerías pero aun no logro usarlas adecuadamente.

AYUDA!!

Answer (score 0):

Mira este package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

Para tu ejemplo puntual puedes usarlo de la siguiente manera

```
const Json2csvParser = require('json2csv').Parser;
const fields = ['id', 'burstTime', 'arribo'];
const myCars = [{
    "id": "p1",
    "burstTime": "3",
    "arribo": "0"
}, {
    "id": "p2",
    "burstTime": "4",
    "arribo": "1"
}, {
    "id": "p3",
    "burstTime": "5",
    "arribo": "2"
}];

const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ fields });
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(myCars);

console.log(csv);
```

Luego puedes escribir csv a un archivo o lo que necesites